# matlab - How to detect a specific region of image based on MRI?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I'm doing research to implement automatic segmentation based on MRI (Magnetic Resonance Image) modals. For my case, prostate region is my focus . To make this happen, I'm thinking about these steps: 1. Image Acquisitions (about 20+ patients MRI - DICOM, each patient has around 15-30 slice images, and all these images will be dataset for training, you can see example of the dataset below)

[image]

2. From these dataset, I'm thinking to do manual segmentation with purpose to get the region of prostate (and the size of prostate in each slice is not consistent), so I can get the feature of prostate for any size, as you can see below. The green one is central of prostate, and the red one is peripheral zone of prostate.

   [image]
3. So now, I have feature dataset of all slices, and I'm ready for train it to create classifier model.
4. ?

As I'm still green of MATLAB (sorry for this), I have no idea to train the dataset to create classifier that can detect the region of prostate (in any size), and automatically give a boundary to it. Should I use classifier + segmentation algorithm (level set/active contour) to get this done or only using classifier algorithm can get this done?

I' learning about object detection algorithm such as; Haar-Like Feature, but can get all of this clear (yes, I'm screwed). I would be very grateful if anyone can help me to give a clear idea, and guide me to make this happen, please.

Very Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid this question is way too broad for Stack Overflow, you ask us to summarize a complete research field for you. I would recommend you to first pick which algorithm you want to use, then try to find an example of matlab code for that algorithm online and try to modify that to suit your needs. If you get stuck somewhere in modifying the software, you may have a question [you can ask here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but for now you're first gonna have to dig into some segmentation algorithms yourself first.

Comment: Well, it's just a notion, but if you are looking for a really simple solution, you can use the fact, that only area that is not in grayscale are your coloured borders. Therefore it's not complicated to eliminate just the borders and get coordinates of the bordered area. Would it be sufficient for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that you could get good segmentation using superpixels (SLIC is a good approach for generating these), especially so since your images do not seem particularly complex.  A common approach for building a classifier using superpixels is to train a CRF to learn the correct segmentation.  This is a fairly common approach in computer vision and looks like it should do well given your data.  Further, there are good implementations of both of these approaches in Matlab.

Comment: a big thank you for your suggestion! By confirming it, SLIC is Simple Linear Iterative Clustering Superpixels, and CRF is  Conditional Random Field, am I right? So SLIC superpixels will do the segmentation, and prepare a specific ROI (manually choosen), and CRF will train those ROIs to build a classifier that can specify the probabilistic region of interest, right?

Comment: great! but for what I have read, there are superpixels and supervoxels, is there any difference between these two on implementation?

Comment: Explains the difference between pixel and voxel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel.  So, yes, if you were implementing SLIC, there would be a difference between generating superpixels and supervoxels.

Comment: Again, very thank you! You made my day!